# A property of Cartier operator

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

In [this paper](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enmk/old/nilpconn.pdf) theorem 7.2 on page 200, they define the inverse Cartier operators with respect to some properties.

My question is how to read the third condition

$$C^{-1}(dW^{-1}f)=[f^{p-1}df]\text{ in }\mathscr{H}^1(F_*\Omega_{X/S}^\bullet)$$

where $W:X^{(p)}\to X$ and $F:X\to X^{(p)}$ are the canonical maps when defining Frobenius twists.

First, what is this $W^{-1}$?

Second, where does this $f$ lives? Actually, I see this quite often in papers to give a morphism of sheaves. Usually, they write define by "some elements on sheaves", $f\in\mathscr{F}$. Does it mean defining for global sections? I don't think it is enough to define just on global sections, right? It should be that we give morphisms of the sections on each open sets.